# built-in support for ealy stopping in tensorflow estimator

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a built-in early stopping  function in tensorflow? I check the hooks that provided by tf.Estimator, don't find anything. Or I need implement by myself?

Comment: Perhaps it is possible with an [Experiment](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment), not sure. At least you can run periodic eval on a seperate validation set.

Comment: ok. I took a look at the Experiment. mybe I can pass monitor: tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor into experiment. I wil try it and update the result later on.

Answer (score 0):

@Maxime,
Experiment works！　here is part of my code, in case you are interest in the answer. There is feature is in the contrib, so it maynot be stable.

```
config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.train_dir)
# config = config.replace(sess_config=sess_config)
tf.logging.set_verbosity(logging.INFO)
validation_monitor = monitors.ValidationMonitor(
    input_fn=functools.partial(input_fn, subset="evaluation"),
    eval_steps=128,
    every_n_steps=101,
    early_stopping_metric="accuracy",
    early_stopping_rounds = 1000
)
run_monitors = [validation_monitor]
tf.contrib.learn.learn_runner.run(
    get_experiment_fn(train_input_fn=functools.partial(input_fn,subset="training"),
                      eval_input_fn=functools.partial(input_fn,subset="evaluation"),
                      train_steps=FLAGS.train_steps,
                      eval_steps=100,
                      train_hooks=run_monitors,
                      model_fn=model_fn_cnn
                      ),
    run_config = config
)
```